# How to handle comments that are answers?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

Should I flag comments that actually are answers? And if I should do so, how should I flag them?

Or is it better to write some "Make your comment an answer" comment (which seems pretty verbose to me)?

Should I turn them into an answers myself (which I would consider impolite due to potential loss of reputation)?

Or should I even ignore that?

Comment: Just ask them to convert it. If they feel it would make a good answer, they'll convert it, otherwise it's likely that the comment alone wouldn't have made a very good answer.

Comment: If I'm answering in comments it is because I don't have the time or the knowledge for a comprehensive good answer or just don't want to answer, it's a hint and I would never feel it as impolite if the OT or someone else will make a good answer from those hints. If someone want's to answer, he has to do so, there is no `foot in the door` from a comment.

Comment: I would personally prefer to be asked to convert if someone felt my comment was worth being an answer. Regardless, look at the duplicate for more suggestions.

Comment: Feel free to add as an answer, but maybe give them some time to answer, or even prompt them to do so.  Sometimes I will give a partial answer via comment either to get them started or make sure I understand what they are after.  Meanwhile I might be composing an answer.

Comment: If I feel a question is of low quality and should be deleted, I might answer it in a comment so that a potentially upvoted answer doesn't stop it from being deleted later. Usually I'll combine that with a downvote/closevote. In those cases I think it would be plain wrong to convert it to an answer.